# How to link file with assets under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, windows-explorer

If you save any webpage under Windows, you will notice it creates a folder which is "linked" to the html file, like:

(file)   Twitter.htm

(folder) Twitter_files

If you try to copy either file or folder, e.g. Twitter.htm, Twitter_files will also be copied along.

Can I achieve this functionality somehow? I am asking both as a plain Windows user and pro grammatically (e.g. a C++ API). I don't see any flag in the file properties to make them linked.

Comment: The linkage is implied by the file and directory names. No special properties are needed.